# Append an integer to a string as a string

Tags: t-sql

Trying to do something like this:

```
select 'Setup for Car ' + CAST(varchar(50), @CarID) + ' for user ' + CAST(varchar(5), @UserID)
```

doesn't work, not sure what the syntax would be then for T-SQL.  I've hunted around, have not found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user either of these:

```
select 'Setup for Car ' + Convert(varchar(50), @CarID) + ' for user ' + Convert(varchar(5), @UserID)
```

OR

```
select 'Setup for Car ' + CAST(@CarID as varchar(50)) + ' for user ' + CAST(@UserID as varchar(5))
```

Comment: You can use either of of them, you just have to get the parameters in the correct location. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using CAST wrong. It should be

```
CAST(@Variable AS WhatYouAreCastingTo)
```

[Here is a fiddle showing this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1979)

Remember, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is your friend :)